# Hotspots show up in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a picture with polygonal hotspots. In IE the hotspots are visible and I do not want that effect. How can I prevent this? Thanks

Go here: http://animactions.ca/Animactions/volet_entreprise.php with IE and select one

Comment: Do you have a link to a demonstration, or offer the picture and associated code? Are you using an image-map of some kind?

Comment: What do you mean they're visible? Hotspots are just supposed to be used to create links on top of an image, they shouldn't put anything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the style 'outline: 0;' on all of your links in your image map?

You can try:

```
a, area {
    outline: 0;
}
```

This will remove the ugly outline around any links on your site that appear when you click them.